# Does google index aria attributes?

Tags: css, html, seo, wai-aria

I need to be sure that the cell content will be indexed by Google (and other search engines) with the label.
In my case I can't put label directly in td tag

html:

```
<td><a href="#" aria-label="prof. ">Jan Kowalski</a></td>
```

css:

```
a:before {
    content: attr(aria-label);
}
```

How this cell will be indexed by google? only 'Jan Kowalski' or maybe 'prof. Jan Kowalski'?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons described in the [tag:seo] tag.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read "[Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618)" to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not). General SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no evidence of search engines paying any attention to ARIA attributes. They are not meant for such use but for making application-like HTML documents more accessible. In particular, [`aria-label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label) associates an “accessible name” for an “object”, which is expected to be interactive, such as a button, and the “accessible name” suggests what the button or other element *does*.

So it is very unrealistic to expect that search engines extract information from such attributes. They index textual content, though they *may* additionally index some data in some `meta` tags or selected attributes, mainly `alt` and `title`.